# Communication between VLANs doesnt work

Tags: linux

[image: setup]

Hello i'm trying to make this set up in GNS3

I can do remote management from client 5 (ssh) to both switches
I can ping from client 1 to client 2 and client 6
I can ping from client 3 to client 4
These are in the same VLAN (20 and 10)

I did a basic configuration on switch 1 and switch 2, these are multilayer switches

I cant ping between VLAN 10 and VLAN 20 (for exp client 1 -> client 6)
Network is unreachable

Comment: This is a networking question, not a Unix/Linux question.

Comment: The point with VLANs is that they partition a physical network into virtual networks that act like they were separate networks. You can think of your two VLANs as if they were two disconnected networks. If you want hosts on one LAN to talk to the other LAN, you will have to add a router with one port on each LAN, and set up routing between them.